# Format BigDecimal in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, bigdecimal

I'm using Spring 3 with JPA.

I've got my Product class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="price", precision=12, scale=2)    
    private BigDecimal price;
```

The problem is that when I fill my Product creation form with a price like "1.20" I get in my views "1.2". The trailing zero disappears.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `JSTL` format taglib to format the display of a `BigDecimal`.

To format a `BigDecimal` include a `Product` as an attribute and reference the `price` field via the instance of `Product` using `JSP EL`.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price }" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```

You should also include the `JSTL FMT` taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

And will need to place the JSTL API & Implementation Jars on your classpath:

[Jar Files](https://jstl.java.net/download.html)

Comment: Thank you @KevinBowersox . I tried with `<div class="item-price pull-left"><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" minFractionDigits="2"/></div>` (with the taglib and jar files) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I'm calling ${product.price} inside DataTables, so it's been taken via Json. I added a @JsonSerialize annotation and a formatter class and I obtained the right value. I'll try your jstl outside json and I'll let you know :)